# Concatenate outputs of the commands

Tags: concatenation

Can someone please help me to concatenate the outputs of the two commands?

```
finger | awk '{print $2,$3}' | uniq | sed '1d'

system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/{print $NF}'
```

The output should be `firstnamelastname.Serialnumber.local`

Answer (score 0):

you can affect result of two commands in variables to be able to concatenate them in a result one

```
first=$(finger | awk '{print $2,$3}' | uniq | sed '1d')
second=$(system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/{print $NF}')
result="$first.$second"
echo $result;
```